# how pass parameter to object manager get

Tags: magento2, object-manager

I have a ProductFactory , it's construction must manual pass a parameter, But I don't know how to pass it.
I use

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $objectManager->get(ProductFeedCaptureFactory::class, ['instanceType' => $type]);
```

The ProductFactory code below:

```
class ProductFactory    
{
/**
 * Object Manager instance
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
 */
protected $_objectManager = null;
/**
 * Instance name to create
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_instanceName = null;

/**
 * Factory constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
 * @param string $instanceType  ftp、http、file
 * 
 */
 public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,  $instanceType )
 {
 }
}
```

But I got an exception :

> Missing required argument $instanceType

How I fix it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `create` instead of get to create a new instance of the factory with this call instead of accessing an existing shared instance